# How to prove $\text{Sh}_G(X)\simeq \text{Sh}(G\backslash X)$ when $X$ is a free $G$-space?

Tags: reference-request, representation-theory, sheaf-theory, group-actions

Let $k$ be a field and $X$ be a topological space. We consider Sh$(X)$, the category of sheaves of $k$-vector spaces on $X$.

Let $G$ be a topological group which act on $X$ continuously from the left. Consider the simplicial space $[G\backslash X]_{\cdot}$ where
$$
[G\backslash X]_n=\underbrace{G\times \ldots \times G}_{n\text{ copies of }G\text{'s}}\times X
$$
with structural maps
$$
d_0(g_1,\ldots, g_n,x)=(g_2,\ldots,g_n,g_1^{-1}x);
$$
$$
d_i(g_1,\ldots, g_n,x)=(g_1,\ldots, g_ig_{i+1},\ldots, g_n,x), ~1\leq i\leq n-1;
$$
$$
d_n(g_1,\ldots, g_n,x)=(g_1,\ldots, g_{n-1},x);
$$
and
$$
s_0(g_1,\ldots, g_n,x)=(e,g_1,\ldots, g_n,x);
$$
$$
s_i(g_1,\ldots, g_n,x)=(g_1,\ldots, g_i,e , g_{i+1},\ldots, g_nx),~1\leq i\leq n-1;
$$
$$
s_n(g_1,\ldots, g_n,x)=(g_1,\ldots, g_n,e,x).
$$

A $G$-equivariant sheaf on $X$ is a pair $(\mathcal{F},\theta)$, where $\mathcal{F}\in \text{Sh}(X)$ and $\theta$ is an isomorphism
$$
\theta: d_0^*\mathcal{F}\overset{\sim}{\to} d_1^*\mathcal{F},
$$
satisfying the cocycle condition
$$
d_2^*\theta\circ d_0^*\theta=d_1^*\theta, \text{ and } s_0^*\theta=\text{id}_{\mathcal{F}}.
$$
We denote the category of $G$-equivariant sheaves on $X$ by $\text{Sh}_G(X)$.

If the $G$-action on $X$ is free, then we should have a category equivalence
$$
\text{Sh}(G\backslash X)\overset{\sim}{\to}\text{Sh}_G(X).
$$

This result seems to be well-known and we do not require $G$ is compact.

> My question is: how to prove this equivalence? Is there a reference with detailed proof?